# Segmentation fault in bitwise component sum

Tags: c++, string, segmentation-fault, sum, bit-manipulation

So my lab is basically take a string in from cin, separate it into components (into its various chars) and then do a component sum of all the chars using bitwise operators. Finally, print out the result. This is what I have.

I get a segmentation fault right after entering the first string.

[EDIT]Runs now without segFaults, but I get the result = 0, aInt = 0, and bInt = 0.
No idea why?
I typed a = hello and b = world

```
using namespace std;
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>                                                              
#include <stdlib.h> 

int main()
{
    string a, b;
    char *aStopstring, *bStopstring;
    unsigned long aInt, bInt;

    cout<<"Please enter a string: "<<endl;
    cin>> a;

    const char* aString = a.c_str();

    cout<<"Please enter another string: "<<endl;
    cin>> b;

    const char* bString = b.c_str();

    aInt = strtoul(aString, &aStopstring, 2);                                                       
    bInt = strtoul(bString, &bStopstring, 2); 

    cout<<aInt<< "     " << bInt<<endl;                               

    unsigned int c = aInt&bInt;
    unsigned int d = aInt^bInt;
    c = c>>1;
    unsigned int result = c^d;

    cout<<"The sum is: "<< (int)result <<endl;

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: You're not allocating any of your strings.  They are simply dangling pointers which do not point to valid memory locations.  Also, this is C++; use `std::string`

Comment: I suggest you have a look at http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i49_SNt4yfk and after that replace char* by std::string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

aString and bString are not allocated.

```
char* aString = new char[255];
char* bString = new char[255];
```

Make sure you delete those pointers when you're done.

```
delete[] aString;
delete[] bString;
aString = 0x0;
bString = 0x0;
```

If you're not *required* to use char* for input, you can use an `std::string` (so you don't have to worry about allocating enough space for your input) and then work with the underlying char buffer of the std::string by using `c_str()`.

Example:

```
std::string aString;
std::cin >> aString;
const char* buffer = aString.c_str();
```

Comment: Of note: `delete[]` is particularly important here, careful not to simply use `delete`!

Comment: Thanks! though delete gives me weird errors? No idea why, typed it in just as you did. Without it, though, it runs, just gives me 0 for everything

Comment: What is the weird error? Also what inputs are you using? Note that you're using base 2 for the strtoul so you need to be passing it binaries.

Comment: *** glibc detected *** ./main: free(): invalid pointer: 0x0000000001998058 ***

Followed by a bunch of gibberish

I'm passing the first string as 'hello' and the second as 'world'

Comment: @DulceRios I just read your edit, you should *not* delete the `const char*` buffers if you're using std::string. Note that in my second example I don't delete the `const char* buffer` because it will be taken care of by `std::string aString` when it goes out of scope.

Comment: @DulceRios No problem at all! :)

Answer (score 0):

Add a statement such as `aString = new char[80];` before the first time you try to read somethiong into that variable.